# Add to menu using addIntentOptions providing multiple intents for a single activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-manifest, intentfilter

I want to use `addIntentOptions` to drive my menus when ever possible. This seems the cleanest way to provide them. Rather than explicitly detailing activities, simply ask for a menu listing all the activities which are available for my data item.

So I'm trying to put together a context menu for a `ListView`. It works great. Only problem is that I have an activity that has two intents that consume my data type, and only the first shows up.

The activity in question in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity android:name=".ui.MyActivity" android:label="The title">
    <intent-filter android:label="First context label">
        <action android:name="com.sample.action.FIRST_ACTION" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.SELECTED_ALTERNATIVE" />
        <data android:scheme="myscheme" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter android:label="Second context label">
        <action android:name="com.sample.action.SECOND_ACTION" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.SELECTED_ALTERNATIVE" />
        <data android:scheme="myscheme" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The code to generate the context menu

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, 
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, view, menuInfo);

    Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("myscheme", getOpaqueUriOfSelectedItem(view), null)

    Intent intent = new Intent(null, uri);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_SELECTED_ALTERNATIVE);

    // Search and populate the menu with acceptable offering applications.
    menu.addIntentOptions(
            0, // Menu group to which new items will be added
            0, // Unique item ID (none)
            0, // Order for the items (none)
            this.getComponentName(), // The current Activity name
            null, // Specific items to place first (none)
            intent, // Intent created above that describes our requirements
            0, // Additional flags to control items (none)
            null); // Array of MenuItems that correlate to specific items
                    // (none)
}
```

As I say, the first intent of the activity shows up in the context menu and behaves like a dream. But I don't see the second intent, and I see no good reason it shouldn't show up. If Android only allows one intent with a particular category per activity, that's a pretty lame restriction.

I can see myself building a dummy activity that simply hands off to `MyActivity`. But that's clumsy and I'd like to avoid it if possible.

**EDIT**: Looking at the intent that is passed through to an activity from a context menu (or option menu, presumably), even if both intents showed up in the menu, the activity wouldn't have enough information to tell which intent was selected, as within the activity `getIntent().getAction()` is null.

This seems like an unfortunate oversight. Surely it isn't that unusual to have an activity that can consume a type of data in more than one way?

Unless one of you kind folk know something I've missed, it looks like I'm going to be creating my dummy activities.

**EDIT**: As CommonsWare suggested, I tried using `queryIntentActivityOptions`. I added in this code before `menu.addIntentOptions` in my code above.

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
final List<ResolveInfo> available = 
    pm.queryIntentActivityOptions(this.getComponentName(), null, intent, 0);
```

And in the debugger I found that `available` didn't include both of the available intents for `MyActivity`. So the issue isn't within `addIntentOptions`, it's deeper, within `queryIntentActivityOptions` somewhere.

Comment: @SamStephens: FWIW, Google has been backpedaling from `addIntentOptions()` pretty much since Android 1.0. That's not to say  you cannot use it, but don't expect that pattern to get a whole lotta love going forward. In particular, it would not surprise me in the least if there are bugs for odd cases like yours. Consider using `queryIntentActivityOptions()` and populating the menu yourself.

Comment: The list that `queryIntentActivityOptions()` returns will only return one entry for each Activity matched.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Is there any documentation of Google's rational for this available, or anything about what we're expected to do instead. `addIntentOptions()` is a great way to set up a context menu. A minimal amount of code, and almost all the information declarative, not imperative. Especially compared to other context menus I've seen, with screeds of code and changes required in multiple places to change the available options.

Comment: @codelark: That's the behaviour I'm seeing. And it seems daft. If an activity can consume a class of data in more than one fashion, allowing you to specify more than one intent and have the activity matched more than once seems the logical way to do it. Imagine an activity that will send the details of one contact to another contact. There are two ways to use this activity can consume a contact: either send the details of the contact to another contact; or send the details of another contact to the contact. I can't provide both options in menus without a dummy activity, or manual menu creation

Comment: @SamStephens I am away from my dev environment, but I posted an answer below that I believe should work. The mojo is in the flags. If `addIntentOptions` passes the flags through to `queryIntentActivityOptions`, then using the value `GET_INTENT_FILTERS` should do exactly what you want.

Comment: Tried direct with `queryIntentActivityOptions` with this flag, and still only get one of the two intents. Interestingly, `queryIntentActivityOptions` claims it removes duplicates so I tried with `queryIntentActivities` with and without the flag, but still only get one of the two activities. I've been trying to look through the source code on http://android.git.kernel.org to work out the logic, but the code doing this is too twisty and calls too many things to really follow without a lot of time I don't have right this minute.

Comment: @SamStephens: They recommend a dialog, populated by `queryIntentActivities()` or `queryIntentActivityOptions()`. Partly, they were focused on adding intent options to option menus, which they felt could result in unwieldy menu sizes. Bear in mind that the whole `CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE`/`CATEGORY_SELECTED_ALTERNATIVE` stuff is only needed for `addIntentOptions()`, so you might consider dropping those off for your `queryIntentActivities()` tests.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Have you got any sources for these recommendations? I'm wanting to blog about this. I find the paternalism of Google "protecting" us from unwieldy menus annoying. For some classes of application where you know that other applications will never use your data types, you can easily control the size of context menus generated by `addIntentOptions()`, and the way the menu is generated implicitly is very tidy.

Comment: @SamStephens: "Have you got any sources for these recommendations?" -- they're buried in the `android-developers` Google Group somewhere. "I find the paternalism of Google "protecting" us from unwieldy menus annoying." -- there is nothing preventing you from using `addIntentOptions()`. However, Google is not using it in their own apps and no longer recommends it. Furthermore, even if `addIntentOptions()` were to be removed (*very* unlikely), there is nothing preventing you from using `queryIntentActivities()` for use with a menu.

Comment: @SamStephens: And, of course, you are absolutely welcome to create your own reusable library for creating awesome option and context menus that are driven by registered intent filters or anything else that is "a minimal amount of code, and almost all the information declarative, not imperative". And, there is nothing preventing you from convincing as many developers as you like to adopt your library and its conventions.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare. Hopefully I didn't come across too argumentative, your help, information and suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: @SamStephens: BTW, here's the android-developers thread in question: http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg44159.html

Comment: @CommonsWare: Ahh, interesting. Really though, my problems aren't actually with `addIntentOptions()` as such, it's with the way `queryIntentActivities()` works (one result per activity), and with the way data is passed to an activity about the intent that called it. See my answer for more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach cannot work because `queryIntentActivityOptions()`, and the methods that call it, don't work in the way needed for my approach.

For my approach to work, you would need to get a result per intent-filter matched, which could result in multiple results per activity. Also, you would need to get information about which intent-filter matched in the result, specifically the action of the intent-filter.

However `queryIntentActivityOptions()` doesn't find **intent-filters**, it finds **activities** with at least one matching intent-filter. Meaning you only get one result per activity. The result also provides no information about the intent-filter that matched your intent.

This approach makes sense, but it's a shame that it doesn't allow for an activity to provide multiple ways to consume a particular intent.

So my workaround is to create fake activities for any activity with more than one action, that then hand off to the real activity.

So the sample manifest I included in the question would become

```
<activity android:name=".ui.MyActivity" android:label="The title" />
<activity android:name=".ui.MyActivityFirstAction" android:label="First action">
    <intent-filter android:label="First context label">
        <action android:name="com.sample.action.FIRST_ACTION" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.SELECTED_ALTERNATIVE" />
        <data android:scheme="myscheme" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".ui.MyActivitySecondAction" android:label="Second action">
    <intent-filter android:label="Second context label">
        <action android:name="com.sample.action.SECOND_ACTION" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.SELECTED_ALTERNATIVE" />
        <data android:scheme="myscheme" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

MyActivityFirstAction and MyActivitySecondAction would simply call MyActivity with the appropriate action and data.

I don't really like this scheme that much, but it still keeps all the actions that are in context menus defined in XML data rather than in code, and allows me to use `addIntentOptions()`.

I still consider `addIntentOptions()` very tidy, and even if CommonTasks tells me that Google have been backpedaling from it, I will keep using it until I come across issues.

**EDIT**: As CommonsWare suggests, it would also be possible to create your own library for doing this in a non-hackish fashion. As I end up with more applications, I will probably move in this direction (unless I find an existing method I like better :-) ).